# Apptentive iOS SDK clear conversation

Tags: ios, objective-c, apptentive

Using Apptentive SDK for iOS (https://github.com/apptentive/apptentive-ios).

When a user logs out of my app, I need a way to clear the conversation that is saved by Apptentive.

Have tried:

```
[[ATConnect sharedConnection] setInitialUserName:@""];
[[ATConnect sharedConnection] removeCustomPersonDataWithKey:@"name"];
```

Comment: I often find source code to be the best documentation.

Comment: @pkamb - it's been more than a year, is it "almost done"?